# Why does Matlab add this line to plot when saving?

Tags: matlab, plot

I've been trying to plot some inequalities in Matlab.

When it shows in Matlab figure, it looks right:

[image]

But when I save the figure, I get this annoying yellow line (both when saved manually and when saved in code):
[image]

---

The code which produces the plot is:

```
function [  ] = plotInequalities( ~ )

pRange = linspace(1/2,1,1000);
cRange = linspace(0,1,1000);
[P, C] = meshgrid(pRange,cRange);
ineq1 = P >= 2/3;           
ineq2 = C.*P.*(3-4.*P)./(2.*P+C.*(2-4.*P)) >= 1-P; 
ineq3 = C <= 3.*P.*(1-P)./(2.*(-6.*P.^2+6.*P-1));
rest = ~ineq1 & ~ineq2 & ~ineq3;                      
pl = figure
hold on
c = 2:5; 
contourf(pRange, cRange, c(2) * ineq2, [c(2), c(2)], 'c')  
contourf(pRange, cRange, c(3) * ineq3, [c(3), c(3)], 'y')  
contourf(pRange, cRange, c(4) * rest, [c(4), c(4)], 'r') 
contourf(pRange, cRange, c(1) * ineq1, [c(1), c(1)], 'b')  
legend('\{A,AB\}', '\{A,B\}', '\{A,AB, B\}', '\{A\}')
xlabel('P')
ylabel('C')
saveas(pl, 'out.png','png');
end
```

I'm using Matlab R2014a on Windows 8.

---

> **Any idea as to why this happens?**

Comment: Please give more details. Show the code you used to generate the plot, and save the figure (which format?). Which version of matlab (and the platform) may be useful to know too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there is an overlap between your domain `ineq1` and `ineq3`.

If you set the renderer of the figure to anything else than `painter` (e.g. `opengl` or `zbuffer`) you will see the line which represent the border of your domain `ineq3` (which should be hidden under `ineq1`)

When the figure is printed with the Matlab engine (for `png`,`jpg`,`tiff` etc ...), I couldn't force the `print` command to use the `painter` renderer. If you use one of the format rendered with the gostscript engine (`pdf`, `bmp`,`pcx`,`pcm`,...) then the proper output is produced.

If you want to stick to `png` output, the simple way around is to ensure there is no overlap between your domains before you send them to the `contourf` function. So in your case just add the line:

```
ineq3(ineq3==ineq1) = false ;
```

just before you call the different `contourf`, and the ouput will be OK in the figure *and* in the image saved (because there will be no ghost line to confuse the rendering engine).

Of course with this method, the order of overlap is important. This solution assume you want to see the full domain `ineq1` and it has priority over the domain `ineq3`. If you want a different priority you have to change which domain override the other.

*PS: and if you want the border of all domains to be visible, consider using patches and transparency so the overlaps will be more obvious.*